# Use transactions for an sqlite query?

Tags: go, sqlite

I'm working on an assignment that has us using transactions using sqlite. This is the part I'm struggling with:

> open the database and start a transaction. Call the function to read in all the zones with that transaction, then commit the transaction when it returns

Since I'm only querying the database and not inserting/updating, I don't think I need to do much in terms of setting up the transaction. This is what I'm working with

```
database, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./world.db")
tx, _ := database.Begin()
rows, err := database.Query("SELECT id, name FROM zones")
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
} else {
    defer tx.Commit()
}
```

However, since the transaction `tx` isn't being used in the query I have no clue how to pass it to a function, so I'm thinking my query is set up wrong. I would think I'd need to use the transaction in the query somehow, maybe something like `tx.Query()`, but I'm at a loss at the moment.

Comment: Transactions only make sense when you have multiple statements that modify the database that you want treated as one big atomic group. If all you're doing is a select, there's no point.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_Conn_BeginTx

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `tx.Query`. Review https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `database.Query` with `tx.Query`.

Also, you don't need to use transactions for single query operations.